# No route matches [GET] "/new_user_registration_path"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm making a simple website where users can create accounts and log in. Going from the devise tutorial, I have this in application.html.haml:

```
%ul.nav
    -if user_signed_in?
        %li= link_to "Log out", "destroy_use_session_path", :method => :delete
        %li= link_to "Edit registration", "new_user_registration_path"
    -else
        %li= link_to "Log in", "new_user_session_path"
        %li= link_to "Register", "new_user_registration_path"
```

When I click on register, I get this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/new_user_registration_path"
```

I'm pretty new to rails and this is my first time using devise, so I'm sure it's something simple, but I could use some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths should be without quotes:

```
%ul.nav
  -if user_signed_in?
    %li= link_to "Log out", destroy_use_session_path, :method => :delete
    %li= link_to "Edit registration", new_user_registration_path
  -else
    %li= link_to "Log in", new_user_session_path
    %li= link_to "Register", new_user_registration_path
```